# Getting value of html control using loop with asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, loops

I have to following code

```
<div class="divNewProductsMain" style="margin: 0 34px 0 0">
                        <div class="newProdTextDiv2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtNewCompCode_1" runat="server" class="newProdText2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="divProdcutTotal">
                            <label id="lblNewTotalRow_1" runat="server">
                                0</label>&nbsp;&#8362;
                        </div>
                        <div class="newProdTextDiv2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtNewPrice_1" runat="server" onkeyup="setAmountNewProd(this.id)"
                                class="newProdText2" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="newProdTextDiv2">
                            <input type="text" id="txtNewAmount_1" runat="server" onkeyup="setAmountNewProd(this.id)"
                                class="newProdText2" maxlength="3" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="newProdTextDiv">
                            <input type="text" id="txtNewProdName_1" runat="server" class="newProdText" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

the controls id's run from 1 to 10, so for example I have txtNewCompCode_1, txtNewCompCode_2, txtNewCompCode_3 , and so on until txtNewCompCode_10.

My question is, how I can if it possible to run with loop in code behined on the controls and add only the number of the row it is on, something like txtNewCompCode_ + rowNumber.
I do not like to make each control line of code to take it is value.
I have multiple controls and write line of code to take each value is lot of code.

Comment: But are you sure that your control id's will remain constant in the format from 1 to 10 in the end. Aren't you generating the controls dynamically ?

Comment: @Karan, I do not need to make generate the controls dynamically, the id's will constant from 1 to 10.
It will be too complicated for the end user to enter the number of control and then enter to data, I checking the control and taking only the ones of has data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

[HtmlAgility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

This will give you granular control over the html by passing it. Once it's passed you can access these objects programatically and extract whatever info you want.

Comment: @c0D3I0g1c, it look nice.
You have any example how to work with it?

Comment: There are plently of examples on the website. Just follow the link i posted.

Comment: @c0D3I0g1c, I posted question there, hope they will help me.
Did not find any examples.
For the meanwhile I wrote code for each control, just copy-paste and change the number.